# gradle won't sync plugins anymore

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

Gradle is running an experiment today, where they disable all HTTP communication: https://blog.gradle.org/decommissioning-http

Yesterday, I could sync my project just fine; I am not using a proxy or any other 'funky' setup.

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        ...
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        ...
    }
}

plugins {
    id "com.palantir.docker" version "0.20.1"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

While yesterday I could download the dependencies (--refresh-dependencies), it does not work today.
`./gradlew clean build --refresh-dependencies` now fails with an error:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'myproject-backend'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve gradle.plugin.com.palantir.gradle.docker:gradle-docker:0.20.1.
     Required by:
         project : > com.palantir.docker:com.palantir.docker.gradle.plugin:0.20.1
      > Could not resolve gradle.plugin.com.palantir.gradle.docker:gradle-docker:0.20.1.
         > Could not get resource 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/gradle/plugin/com/palantir/gradle/docker/gradle-docker/0.20.1/gradle-docker-0.20.1.pom'.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/gradle/plugin/com/palantir/gradle/docker/gradle-docker/0.20.1/gradle-docker-0.20.1.pom'.
               > peer not authenticated
```

It's also not related to this specific plugin, all my other projects won't sync either (e.g. spring plugin cannot be synced, flyway plugin cannot be synced etc.).

I tried to upgrade my gradle version to the new 6.0, but this did not help either.
Any advice on how to solve this?

Thank you.

// EDIT: My gradle-wrapper.properties file looks like this:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.0-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

Comment: is there a config file with settings and paths to the repos? maybe one such has http instead of https ?

Comment: I edited my post and added the gradle-wrapper.properties file, there is nothing more :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be related to your java version.

Gradle added support for TLSv3 on the 14.11.2019 (and disabled TLSv1.0) in plugins.gradle.org, and it seems that "old" Java versions have problems with it:

https://status.gradle.com/incidents/q2vq49fndxg0

For us it failed with 11.0.1, and we had to upgrade to 11.0.5

Comment: thanks for your reply, I tried it with Java 13.0.1 and it still did not work :-( 
For the record, I also tried it with 11.0.2

Comment: I don't know about JDK 13, but it is not fixed in 11.0.2 (see https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8213202). Could you try the version Ruben mentioned (11.0.5)?

Comment: Works with 11.0.5. Thank you. =)